# How to call ceil function in c++ from my classes's ceil function

Tags: c++, ceil

I need to delegate 'ceil' function.
My class has method 'ceil', which need to return cpp's native method 'ceil'.
How to call it?

```
double ceil() {
return ceil();
}
```

- this is a recursion

Comment: Where does your "native" `ceil()` come from? If it comes from `<cmath>`, it should be `std::ceil()` in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double ceil() {
    return ::ceil(something); // ceil actually has an argument
}
```

Of course, that above is when you define the method inside the class definition; the following is for when you define the method outside the class:

```
double MyClass::ceil() {
    return ::ceil(something);
}
```

And as the comment suggests, using `std::ceil` from included `<cmath>` is better, because indeed, `::ceil` is not guaranteed to be the `ceil` from the C library.

Comment: For portability, you should use `std::ceil`. There's no guarantee that the C library's names are dumped into the global namespace (unless you're including the deprecated C header, which you shouldn't).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Good point. Still, there are many C++ projects that include C headers in global namespace, so one has to be aware what `::something` means.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify that you mean `std::ceil` by writing `std::ceil`.

That assumes you're including the C++ header, `<cmath>` not the deprecated C header `<math.h>`. In that case, and if you don't feel like including the correct header, it's in the global namespace and accessible as `::ceil`.

Remember that it takes an argument, so the code you've posted won't work even after qualifying it.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::ceil inside your customized ceil.

Better would be Have a cast operator to double, as

operator double() 
within your class to convert your data to double and call ceil(obj) wherever needed, so, you don;t have ceil as member within your class, and your object gets converted to double (through your cast operator) and std::ceil gets called automatically.

Comment: And suddenly objects of that class are automatically convertible to `bool`.

Comment: Have another cast operator that converts to double

Comment: Unless it makes sense for the class to be generally convertible to a numeric type, a conversion operator will make it weird and confusing to use. It's certainly not a sensible way to fix this particular issue.

Comment: Well, ceil is applicable for the object in use, double should been applicable too, I guess.